# How to authenticate Users in YouTube api for video uploading

Tags: javascript, java

I'm working on video upload using YouTube api. Ho do we authenticate the user to upload video in to a main YouTube account since so many are needed to upload videos to main account.So we need to authenticate each users.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube uses OAuth 2 for authentication.

Maybe you should consider using Spring social. There is a github project  **spring-social-youtube** which might be helpful:
https://github.com/drankinn/spring-social-youtube

**Spring Social**

The Spring Social project enables your applications to establish Connections with Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) Providers such as Facebook and Twitter to invoke APIs on behalf of Users.

More to read on http://docs.spring.io/spring-social

**Youtube API v3**

The Youtube API Documentation can be found on google developers site  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response.We are planning for an in house application and allowing the users  to upload youtube videos in to main account.But when i implemented the youtube api v3 using javascript its asking for the google account login.But we cant provide the main account credentials to all users.So can i do the authentication to master account automatically without prompting google login.

Comment: @JoiceJoy can't you give other people access to the YouTube account with exactly the permissions they need to upload videos and nothing else?

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller we have only one main account in youtube and we are using the same credentials now for uploading the video.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I mean. You can give multiple people access to the same YouTube account, with their own credentials. That's been a feature of YouTube for years. You don't have to share your main login details just so multiple can upload videos. See here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007

Comment: I have gone through the link you shared and it seems to be good.But can i do the same using an separate application developed using youtube video upload api v3.

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller  
I have gone through the link you shared and it seems to be good.But can i do the same using an separate application developed using youtube video upload api v3.I have found the below reference url for doing this.https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: @Xaver Kapeller ok.But i can explain my plans. (1).We are planning for an  in house application (2)we are choosing temporary workers to upload videos to main account (3) our office do not allow you tube or social site access to these temporary employs. So only way is to develop a separate application to do this .Please advice a better way if available.